# PHP ans msSQL parametirized UPDATE Query using date not updating

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i try update query using php parameterized query but my table doesnt update. on php:

```
$strquery="UPDATE tborder
     SET notestat=?
    , bayar=?
    , tglout=CONVERT(DATETIME,?,103) 
    WHERE nota=? 
    AND tglIn BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,?,103) AND DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,?,103))";
    $stmt1=sqlsrv_query($conn,$strquery,array($nstat,$vbayar,$tglo,$vnota,$stgl,$stgl));
```

and this output i got from SQL profiler how to php code executed

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE tborder
         SET notestat=@P1
        , bayar=@P2
        , tglout=CONVERT(DATETIME,@P3,103) 
        WHERE nota=@P4 
        AND tglIn BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,@P5,103) AND DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@P6,103))',N'@P1 varchar(3),@P2 varchar(5),@P3 varchar(16),@P4 varchar(1),@P5 varchar(16),@P6 varchar(16)'
        ,'confuse','50000','02/04/2017 08:31','2','01/04/2017 00:00','01/04/2017 00:00'
    go
    ---------------------
    (0 row(s) affected)
```

Q:how to write quoted date?

Comment: Could the issue be that you're trying to update records between 01/04/2017 00:00 and 01/04/2017 00:00 and there simply aren't any records?

Comment: yes you are right if i not add DATEADD function from sql server,  my mistake. the date is generated from javascript function i forgot with get month() function the month is start from 0. i attempt to update data on month may not in apr. i think my code just fine. thanks to point the date.